# Iframe is not being shown in mozila, but works properly in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook, iframe

I had inserted facebook plugin box via iframe.Mozila firefox was showing facebook plugin box of my website till yesterday. But  when I checked my website today, I found only blank spaces instead of facebook plugin. Iframe is properly showing plugin box in chrome, but Mozila firefox doesn't work. When I searched in google, I found that "newer firefox version doesn't support https in iframe, try object instead of Iframe,". My question is how to change iframe to embed or any idea to solve this problem

**This page is shown in chrome but doesn't show in mozila**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffedikhola%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you googled is total nonsense.